# How to relate the ut package and base package?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a package created called `update_stage_loading_emp_pkg` which is of length 29  in money_control schema.

Now when I try to create the ut package with name `ut_update_stage_loading_emp_pkg`
 in schema test_control, it is not allowing as default length should not exceed 30.

So I have created some thing like `ut_update_stage_load_emp_pkg`  in test_control schema 
 and in side the test function I have used following

```
procedure test  as 
begin 
   utplsql.run ('ut_update_stage_load_emp_pkg') ;
end;
```

ut is getting executed properly with out any issues.
Now how do i find the link between these 2 packages  in ut  tables  in utplsql schema?

Where can I find that the `ut_update_stage_loading_emp_pkg` is ut package for base package `update_stage_loading_emp_pkg`?

Comment: Instead of making up an arbitrarily abbreviated name, you could use a simpler and predictable name transformation, e.g. `'UT_'||SUBSTR(package_name,1,27)` which would generate the name `ut_update_stage_loading_emp_pk`. If you want to retain the `_pkg` convention it wouldn't be difficult to change the transformation.

Answer (score 1):

UTPLSQL relies on naming conventions to associate unit test code with the packages it tests. There is no mechanism to tie differently named packages together. Of course, it's an open-source package: you're free to extend it yourself...

I think the easiest solution would be to trim your core package name to 27 characters. There's a lot of padding in `update_stage_loading_emp_pkg`.

You could save four characters by ditching the `_pkg`. I think labeling packages as `pkg` is as redundant as labeling tables as `tab` (although that seems fairly common in code posted here so ymmv).

Other abbreviations are `upd` for `update`, `stg` for `stage` and `load` for `loading`.